# Why Gradle's wrapper in Linux has to be started in this way?

Tags: linux, bash, gradle, wrapper

I have a Gradle project with this structure:

```
ls -alh

drwxr-xr-x 9 Xelian 4.0K Aug  5 22:39 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 Xelian 4.0K Aug  5 16:19 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Xelian  465 Aug  5 16:19 build.gradle
drwxrwxr-x 8 Xelian 4.0K Aug  5 16:38 buildSrc
drwxrwxr-x 3 Xelian 4.0K Aug  5 16:19 gradle
drwxrwxr-x 3 Xelian 4.0K Aug  5 16:45 .gradle
-rwxrwxrwx 1 Xelian 5.0K Aug  5 17:29 gradlew
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Xelian 2.3K Aug  5 16:19 gradlew.bat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Xelian 17K Aug  5 16:19 README.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Xelian   30 Aug  5 16:19 settings.gradle
```

And to execute the gradlew bash file I write:

```
gradlew -v
```

Output:

```
No command 'gradlew' found, did you mean:
 Command 'gradle' from package 'gradle' (universe)
gradlew: command not found
```

If I write :

```
 ./gradlew -v
```

Everything works fine.

Does ./ mean current directory?

Comment: Yes `./` means current dir. If You omit it the command will be searched in $PATH variable and it's not defined there. You must point directly.

Comment: A good way to solve this problem is https://github.com/cbeams/dotfiles/blob/home/bin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you type:

```
command
```

Your `shell` will search all the directories listed in your `$PATH` environment variable, in order, for an executable with the name "**command**".

When you type:

```
./command
```

The `./` part explicitly tells your shell that you want to execute the file named "**command**" in the current directory (`.` is interpreted as the current directory).

If you want to be able to run it with just `command`, you will have to add the current directory to your `PATH`, or move the executable to somewhere already on your `PATH`

Comment: Additional information on the dot slash `./`: http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html